# How to tokenize all the files from all the subfolders

Tags: python, nlp, dataset, tokenize

I have a dataset which consists of 50 subfolders and each of these subfolders has 20-30 files without extension. What I wanted to do is tokenizing the texts in the files for each subfolders, and write it to file with subfolder's name. For example;
Let's say subfolder1 has 25 files and I want to tokenize those 25 files together, and write it to a file named "subfolder1". And I want to do it for all the subfolders in the main folder.

I have tried some pieces of this [code](https://github.com/ayushoriginal/Multi-Document-Summarization/blob/master/MMR/summary_util/summary_utils.py) but it gives PermissionError since it can not read a folder.

```
    mainfolder="path\\to\\mainfolder"

    def ls(path):
        return [os.path.join(path, item) for item in os.listdir(path)]


    def load_file_sents(path):
        return [sent.lower()
                for sent in tokenize.sent_tokenize(open(path).read())]


    def load_collection_sents(path):
        sents = []
        for f in ls(path):
            sents.extend(load_file_sents(f))
        return sents


    def get_sentences(path):
        """ loads sentences from the given path (collection or file) """
        sents = []
        try:
            # treat as a single file
            open(path).read()
            sents = load_file_sents(path)
        except IOError:
            # it's a directory!
            sents = load_collection_sents(path)
        return sents


    def get_toks(path):
        return [tokenize.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in get_sentences(path)]

    get_toks(mainfolder)
```

This is the error it gives:

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-a6f316499b2c> in get_sentences(path)
     37         # treat as a single file
---> 38         open(path).read()
     39         sents = load_file_sents(path)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

I have tried merging the first two functions into one, and make sure it will read files, but this time it just returned tokens of the first file of the first subfolder. If you know how to solve this issue or a better way to do it, your help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `tokenizing` the text in files?

Comment: Like splitting the documents into words and sentences. ['like', 'splitting', 'the', 'documents', 'into', 'words', 'and', 'sentences']  @Sukumar Rdjf

Comment: Did you try going through all the subfolders and issuing a `cat *` command, capture output, split it based on **blank space** , convert that `list` to a `set`.and again to `list` and write that list to a file named after the subfolder name. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I wrote a script to concatenate the files from subfolders, and it solved my problem for now. But it would be great if someone could explain how to process all the files from all the subfolders in a way that each subfolder will be treated as a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the contents of all the files from ***`current`*** and ***`sub-folders`*** using the following command

`find . -type f -exec cat {} +`

Redirect the output to a variable using `Subprocess.check_output` and perform tokenization on that variable.